# How to Induce read-only to Linux filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, readonly

I've read in several places that during an I/O error to the system log file most Linux distributions go to read-only mode. They followed with a procedure for how to recover from it.

This is all fine, but I'm looking for a way to induce read-only mode to Linux filesystem. Is there a quick and dirty way to cause an I/O error for the system to panic?

Comment: What's false? That I actually read it or my conclusions?

Comment: Sorry, I had to qualify that which is why I deleted it.  They certainly do not go into RO on I/O error, and I'm very dubious they would specifically because of I/O error on the "system log file" -- which system log file?   It would not be a very good feature if it were *any* system log file, since they do not need to all be on one fs.  This is the first I've heard of it, and I think **you have misunderstood something** you've read, so posting an actual link to a reference (rather than potentially **disseminating hearsay**) would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify if actually corrupting the FS is acceptable you may want to look at this Q&A: https://serverfault.com/questions/40302/how-to-corrupt-a-file-system :)

Note: you'd need to corrupt the root filesystem or a swap partition to cause the system to panic, a regular non-critical partition will be just switched to readonly mode but the system can survive without panic.